# Redirect domain to .com in django in url.py

Tags: django

I have a website in Django, hosted in Heroku.
I have 2 domains, registered in different places:
mysite.com and mysite.com.br

I don't want to be penalized by Google for having 2 domains with the same website, therefor I would like to redirect everyone who enters **mysite.com.br to mysite.com**.

I entered in the DNS mysite.com.br(Not hosted anywhere) CNAME mysite.com(hosted in Heroku), which makes the user actually access the Heroku content, but the url keeps the .BR ....

So the Heroku support told me to do the redirection in the application. In this case, what's the best practice to redirect? I would imagine to do that in the url.py, but how can I do that if the "path" doesnt read the domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the URLs. I would write some middleware to check the host via `request.get_host` and redirect if you're not on the canonical one.

In fact it looks like someone has already written this: [django-enforce-host](https://github.com/dabapps/django-enforce-host).